# android sqlite displaying database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to create an application and I am stuck!

This is what I already have:

**Database filled with a list of different strings, for example different animals - And a way to define if the information that is put in by the user is already in the database or not**

What I want:

**When the user types in the correct name of one animal, I would like to display the ROWID of that specific animal, the animal "bear" should have the ID of 54 and this is what I would like to display to the user**

I have the following code in my `databasehelper`:

```
      Public boolean insertInfo(String info){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] cols = new String[]{COL_1, COL_2};

        Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME_LAND, cols, COL_2 + "=?", new String[]{"" + info}, null, null, null);
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            return false;
        } else return true;
    }
```

And this is the code in my `MainActivity` that is depending on this section of the helper:

```
 public void AddData() {
       btnAddData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                  boolean isInserted = myDb.insertInfo(editName.getText().toString());
                     if (isInserted)
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        editName.setText(null);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

What I would like help with, is to determine how to display the information(ID) of the specific STRING that the user is typing in the EditText, which is the same that is already existing in the DATABASE, in a listview for example.

**After some editing of the code after the answers I got here I have this in my MainActivity:**

```
            btnAddData.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editName.getText().toString());

                    if (isInserted) {
                        Cursor data = DatabaseHelper.getID(editName.getText().toString());
                        int id = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex("COL_2"));
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

}

And this in my DatabaseHelper:

```
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public Cursor getID(String ID) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + TABLE_NAME_LAND + " WHERE " + COL_1 + "=?", new String[]{ID});
    return c;

}

public boolean insertData(String name) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //String[] cols = new String[]{COL_1, COL_2};

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + TABLE_NAME_LAND + " WHERE " + COL_1 + "=?", new String[]{name});
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        return false;
    } else return true;
}
}
```

**I get the error while compiling in this section**

```
Cursor data = DatabaseHelper.*getID*(editName.getText().toString());
```

**That Error non-static method getID(String) cannot be referenced from a static context**

Comment: which editText you mean ?

Comment: That would be  the editName in the part where boolean isInserted = myDb.insertInfo(editName.getText().toString());

Comment: Any update for this ?

Comment: yes I am so sorry but i don't get it to work. android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1. ->>>>> for this line of code is the troublemaker int id = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex("COL_2"));

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + TABLE_NAME_LAND + " WHERE " + COL_1 + "=?", new String[]{info});
```

Comment: is this an addition to my code, or should i replace my code with this ?

Comment: @filantropio replace this to your databaseHelper class in insertInfo Method with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this after`(isInserted)`

```
Cursor  data = databaseHelper.getID(editName.getText().toString());
data.moveToFirst(); // add this line
int id = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex("COL_2"));
```

In your databaseHelper, add this code

```
public Cursor getID(String ID)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + TABLE_NAME_LAND + " WHERE " + COL_1 + "=?", new String[]{info});
    return c;
}
```

Comment: I get 2 errors. First one is on "getID" where the error is that it is a non static method that cannot be referenced from a static context. The second error is on the int id where the variable id is never used. I guess the variable id is going to be saving the int of the id from the database, and it is this variable i will be using when wanting to display this int?

Comment: you need to create  `getID()`method in databaseHelper.

Comment: Even after creating the method in my databasehelper "  public Cursor getID(String ID) { ..." I get the error Error:(55, 53) error: non-static method getID(String) cannot be referenced from a static context in my mainactivity right after "isinserted"

Comment: move  `Cursor data = DatabaseHelper.getID(editName.getText().toString());
                    int id = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex("COL_2"));`  to `if(isInserted){}` block.

Comment: The code has yet again been updated and the same error is still there.

Comment: create an object for `DatabaseHelper`.  `DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper()`, than only `Cursor data = db.getID(editName.getText().toString()); int id = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex("COL_2"))`